# How come if condition not work?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

```
           rc = daoMp.retrieveSystemData(argv[2]);
           printf("rc = %d\n");
           if (rc == 0) {
               ErrLog("Mount point found\n");
               printf("Mount point found\n");
               return 4;
           }
           else {
               ErrLog("Could not retrieve system data\n");
               printf("Could not retrieve system data\n");
               return -1;
           }

Output: rc = -208814497
Mount point found
```

How come, if block validation fails?

Comment: look at your first printf. more carefully.

Comment: You have evoked Undefined Behavior best avoided by not using crappy, type-unsafe C-style calls in the first place.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand. There are other parts of code that uses something like `if (rc < 0)` and i followed the same. What do i miss here? Can someone help me?

Comment: look at the answers. rc equals to zero but you don't print rc, you print garbage (-208814497)

Comment: You're writing in C++, but this code reads like C. The answer is easy: [don't write like it were C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328873/c-streams-vs-c-style-io). For a newbie the C-style is much more error prone, and I highly discourage it for people with little experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of this (which you're calling incorrectly, one argument too short):

```
printf("rc = %d\n");
```

Do this:

```
std::cout << "rc = " << rc << '\n';
```

That way, you'll use the proper C++ way of doing this (which would immediately tell you something's off). `printf()` is inherited from C and it's inherently unsafe - your error is a prime example of *why.*

Comment: But C++ is a superset of C, why it won't work i wonder. Any hints please?

Comment: @kingsmasher1 1. C++ is not a superset of C. 2. As I'm saying in the answer, you're calling `printf()` with one argument too short - you're not actually passing `rc` into the function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing second parameter to printf:

```
printf("rc = %d\n", rc);
```

Answer (score 0):

`printf("rc = %d\n");` should be `printf("rc = %d\n", rc);`